# How to communicate back to a page it should display a notification once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a registration page that will report back to the index when the operation was successful. Thet communication, as of right now, is happening through query params.

```
const Foo: React.FC = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [useModal, setUseModal] = useState(false);

    const closeModal = () => {
        setUseModal(false);
    };

    const generateModalContent = (queryContent: ParsedUrlQuery) => {
        if (Object.keys(queryContent).length !== 0) {
            return {
                //key-values from query
            };
        }
    };
    const modalContent = generateModalContent(router.query);

    if (Object.keys(modalContent!).length !== 0 && useModal === false) {
        setUseModal(true);
    }

    return (
        <>
            //unrelated stuff
            {useModal ? <ModalNotification {...modalContent} /> : null}
        </>
    );
};
```

Problem is that every time `closeModal` is called to close the modal, it is shown again since, upon re-render, the query is still there and the cycle will repeat. I'm looking for a clean way to display the data sent by query once, and upon the user closing the modal it doesn't show up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid calling that part of your code in every re-render you must wrap it in a `useEffect` with the correct dependencies like so:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const modalContent = generateModalContent(router.query);

    if (Object.keys(modalContent!).length !== 0 && useModal === false) {
        setUseModal(true);
    }
}, [router]);
```

That way it will only execute when `router` changes and not in an infinite cycle.

You can read more about it in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).